# Is this chipped tire bad enough to replace?

Tags: tires, sidewall-damage

I probably chipped my tire by hitting the curb when parallel parking, the tire only has about 6000 miles on it, but does it look bad enough that I should replace it?

here is the image:
[image: https://imgur.com/a/MxoiWhE]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a scuff at worst. As long as there's no leakage, deformity, cords showing, or bubbling of the rubber, there shouldn't be an issue with it. I would ride on it without too much worry. Just keep an eye on it for the above.

Comment: Yes, just as the man says - agree totally, but DO keep an eye on it...